# Saving FacebookID in Parse Settings

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

This is the statement from Parse Documentation for using Facebook with Parse

To start using Facebook with Parse, you need to:

1. Set up a Facebook app, if you haven't already.
2. Add your application's Facebook Application ID on your Parse application's settings page.

I tried without giving Facebook Application ID in Parse settings. I am able to login and get the user profile information successfully.

so, what is the advantage of providing Facebook Application ID in Parse settings.

Comment: Before downvoting, atleast say why you are downvoting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If We configure this Facebook App Id in our app settings, Parse will only allow Facebook Logins from users who authenticate via that specific app. We can leave it open if we don't want to restrict logins to one specific Facebook app.

Comment: HOW and WHERE do I add this App id in my parse settings, do tell.

Comment: @GeetChoubey I am curious about the same thing. Parse documentation seems to be out of date. I don't see any settings page at all, not even in the parse dashboard.